# Encoding of the response of the Invoke-Webrequest

Tags: powershell

When using cmdlet InvokeWebRequest  against some web with non-english characters, I see no way of defining the encoding of the response / page content.

I use simple GET on http://colours.cz/ucinkujici/ and names of those artists are corrupted. You can try it with this simple line:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://colours.cz/ucinkujici
```

Is this caused by design of the cmdlet?
Can I specify encoding somwhere somehow?
Is there any workaround to get properly parsed response?

Comment: Are you displaying results in the powershell.exe console? It's possible your font doesn't support the characters perhaps.

Comment: I am using powershell ISE v3. I would say this is not the problem, because I have no other problem with my language in powershell ISE or console...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me you are correct :/

Here is one way to get the content right, by saving the response to a file first and then reading it into a variable with the correct encoding. however, you are not dealing with a `HtmlWebResponseObject`:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://colours.cz/ucinkujici -outfile .\colours.cz.txt
$content = gc .\colours.cz.txt -Encoding utf8 -raw
```

This will get you equally far:

```
[net.httpwebrequest]$httpwebrequest = [net.webrequest]::create('http://colours.cz/ucinkujici/')
[net.httpWebResponse]$httpwebresponse = $httpwebrequest.getResponse()
$reader = new-object IO.StreamReader($httpwebresponse.getResponseStream())
$content = $reader.ReadToEnd()
$reader.Close()
```

Should you really want such a `HtmlWebResponseObject`, here is a way to get e.g. stuff from `ParsedHtml` more or less "readable" with `Invoke-WebRequest` (`$bad` vs. `$better`):

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://colours.cz/ucinkujici -outvariable htmlwebresponse
$bad = $htmlwebresponse.parsedhtml.title
$better = [text.encoding]::utf8.getstring([text.encoding]::default.GetBytes($bad))
$bad = $htmlwebresponse.links[7].outerhtml
$better = [text.encoding]::utf8.getstring([text.encoding]::default.GetBytes($bad))
```

---

**Update**: Here is a new take on this, knowing you want to work with `ParsedHtml`.
Once you have your content (see first 2-line snippet which 1) saves response to file and then 2) 'reads' the file content with the correct encoding), you can do this:

```
$ParsedHtml = New-Object -com "HTMLFILE"
$ParsedHtml.IHTMLDocument2_write($content)
$ParsedHtml.Close()
```

Et voilà :]  E.g. `$ParsedHtml.title` now shows correctly, guessing the rest will be OK as well…

Comment: I tried the first example and it works. But bad news is that I have already written all my code against parsedHTML property of the HtmlWebResponseObject. So I tried the third example (which would save me) but unfortunately it doesn`t work for me. It gives me Sigur RA3s (in `$better`) from original Sigur RÃ³s (in `$bad`).

Comment: I used your **Update** part and it works with my old code. Thank you very much, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the workaround with the file, just use the response object properly:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest http://colours.cz/ucinkujici

$encodedString = $response.Content
```

Took me some time to figure out as so many are complaining about a bug in Invoke-WebRequest.

Comment: This simple answer worked for me, not sure why it doesn't have more votes. Maybe things got simpler since the question was originally asked.