# HTMLDocumentClass and getElementsByClassName not working

Tags: powershell, ihtmldocument2

Last year I had powershell (v3) script that parsed HTML of one festival page (and generate XML for my Windows Phone app).

I also was [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705968/encoding-of-the-response-of-the-invoke-webrequest) about it here and it worked like a charm.

But when I run the script this year, it is not working. To be specific - **the method getElemntsByClassName is not returning anything**. I tried that method also on other web pages with no luck.

Here is my code from last year, that is not working now:

```
$tmpFile_bandInfo = "C:\band.txt"
Write-Host "Stahuji kapelu $($kap.Nazev) ..." -NoNewline    
Invoke-WebRequest http://www.colours.cz/ucinkujici/the-asteroids-galaxy-tour/ -OutFile $tmpFile_bandInfo
$content = gc $tmpFile_bandInfo -Encoding utf8 -raw
$ParsedHtml = New-Object -com "HTMLFILE"
$ParsedHtml.IHTMLDocument2_write($content)
$ParsedHtml.Close()
$bodyK = $ParsedHtml.body
$bodyK.getElementsByClassName("body four column page") # this returns NULL
$page = $page.item(0)
$aside = $page.getElementsByTagName("aside").item(0)
$img = $aside.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0)
$imgPath = $img.src
```

this is code I used to workaround this:

```
$sec = $bodyK.getElementsByTagName("section") | ? ClassName -eq "body four column page"
# but now I have no innerHTML, only the lonely tag SECTION
# so I am walking through siblings
$img = $sec.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0)
$imgPath = $img.src
```

This works, but this seems silly solution to me.
Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would consider this a bug.

Comment: Which version on Internet Explorer do you have installed? Inovoke-WebRequest uses IE engine to parse HTML and `getElementsByClassName` was not supported in IE until v9.

Comment: I have IE10 installed on Windows 8.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers What is weird is that it worked year ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved this problem by *abandoning* `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet and by adopting [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com).

I transformed my former sequential HTML parsing into few XPath queries (everything stayed in powershell script). This solution is much more elegant and HtmlAgilityPack is real badass ;) It is really honour to work with project like this!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not a bug but rather that the return where you're seeing NULL is because it's actually a reference to a proxy HTMLFile COM call to the DOM model.

You can force this to operate and return the underlying strings by boxing it into an array @() as such:

```
@($mybody.getElementsByClassName("body four column page")).textContent
```

If you do a Select-Object on it, that also automatically happens and it will unravel it via COM and return it as a string

```
$mybody.getElementsByClassName("body four column page") | Select-Object -Property TextContent
```