# Invoke-WebRequest encoding

Tags: powershell, web, encoding

When I execute:

```
$html = iwr "http://localhost/..."
```

I get Serbian characters as garbage. But when I execute:

```
[Net.HttpWebRequest]$WebRequest =[Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://localhost/...")
[Net.HttpWebResponse]$WebResponse = $WebRequest.GetResponse()
$Reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($WebResponse.GetResponseStream())
$Response = $Reader.ReadToEnd()
```

I see Serbian chars normally. How can I get the same response with Invoke-WebRequest?

**Update:**

The solution at [Encoding of the response of the Invoke-Webrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705968/encoding-of-the-response-of-the-invoke-webrequest) doesn't really work for me. The problem is that here iwr output is saved to file then loaded into variable. However, when this is done, I can't use `ParsedHtml` property which is the primary interest of me.

If I later did what is suggested on mentioned page:

```
$ParsedHtml = New-Object -com "HTMLFILE"
$ParsedHtml.IHTMLDocument2_write($content)
$ParsedHtml.Close()
```

the following doesn't work:

```
$text = $ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName('content')
```

`$ParsedHtml.title` does work but `$ParsedHtml.body -eq $null` is true so I can't access elements. When I access body element from within `iwr.ParsedHtml.body` everything works OK (except the mentioned encoding).

I also tried:

```
$text = [text.encoding]::UTF8.getstring([text.encoding]::default.GetBytes($text))
```

and while *some* chars are now normal, others are not.

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705968/encoding-of-the-response-of-the-invoke-webrequest   Can someone pls flag as duplicate?

Comment: That works, but what I really need is to get `ParsedHtml`. However , doing the `$ParsedHtml.IHTMLDocument2_write($content)` doesn't work for me - body property is always null if I do it this way. Thats the reason I want iwr to work because its ParsedHtml property works OK:     `$text = iwr(...).ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName('content')`

Comment: @majkinetor, can you give an example of your URI.

Comment: @JPBlanc, here is the sample I used: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4ai2j0/parse_local_html_file/. I didn't give real sample because its on Serbian.

Comment: @majkinetor, Can you give the Serbian one to test.