# Powershell output to clipboard without trailing newline?

Tags: powershell, output, clipboard

I need to output the content of a powershell variable to the clipboard, preserving all the newline characters except for the last -trailing- one.
At the moment I am just piping the output of a variable readout to clip.exe, but that gives a trailing newline.

```
$Text = "line1`nline2"
$Text | clip.exe
```

gives the following:

```
"line1,
line2
"
```

I would like it to output

```
"line1,
line2"
```

How might I achieve this?

Comment: Try `Set-Clipboard`.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, that seems to work but it raised a new issue; I can no longer determine which charset the copied text will carry with it (I need it to be in ISO-8859-2) because chcp, which I was using to determine the copied charset before, does not apply to the Set-Clipboard function.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: That's an oddly specific request. The clipboard can convert data on demand. I assume (dangerous assumption there) that PowerShell sets the text as Unicode, and I have a hard time imagining why an application couldn't work with that regardless of which format it preferred. If I (say) copied data from Notepad, it certainly wouldn't end up as ISO-8859-2 -- are you saying whatever you're copying the data to can't handle text from Notepad?

Comment: I am making a program that allows me to select text in my native language (Czech) and at the click of a button add diacritic to it (for example "Tahle veta ma diakritiku" changes to "Tahle věta má diakritiku"). For this purpose I use a server set up by a language university that adds the diacritic, which (rightly) it returns in ISO-8859-2. However that is specified in the response's HTML header, not carried as a property of the text itself, which I need it to be when it is copied in order to be pasted over the current diacritic-less selection.

Comment: That doesn't sound like any sort of clipboard issue, but a problem with the way the HTML output is parsed. If you can see the text correctly with diacritics in PowerShell, it has been successfully converted to Unicode. If not, that should be fixed, rather than trying to pass through the incorrectly decoded characters as-is to `clip` to preserve the code points. To stress this: all text in .NET (PowerShell) and all text in the Windows kernel is in Unicode internally. Conversion to locale-specific formats is only done on demand, at the outer layers.

Comment: I do not parse the HTML at all, I cut it down with string manipulation from the code itself; like so:


`$Form.Fields["text"] = $Content`


`$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 
("https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/cz_accent/" + $Form.Action) -Method POST -Body $Form.Fields`


`$Response = ($Response.Content -split "<PRE>")[1]`


`$Response = ($Response -split "</PRE>")[0]`

Comment: Does `$text`, when printed to the console from PowerShell, look OK to you?

Comment: Yes, after I use `chcp 28592` to change the code page. Without it, no.

Comment: [Edit] I just tried it; PS does not display it correctly even with chcp (though it does output to clip.exe correctly), I'd copied the `chcp` line from a batch file I was using before, and cmd did display all the diacritic, I guess I mistakenly assumed PS would work similarly enough.

Comment: Tried it myself. The problem is that `Invoke-WebRequest` does not handle the content encoding of the response -- the page uses a `meta` directive to specify the encoding, not a header, and `Invoke-WebRequest` isn't smart enough to understand that. The result is *mojibake*. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705968/encoding-of-the-response-of-the-invoke-webrequest) mentions the issue, but I'm not enamored of the solutions presented there. A HTML parser would work, but is heavy stuff.

Comment: To a first approximation, this should work: `$decodedContent = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2").GetString([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes($response.Content))`. This is relying on the (dangerous) assumption that `Invoke-WebRequest` will fall back to Windows-1252 if it has no specific encoding information, which I think is semi-reliable by arcane rules I can't remember.

Comment: It works! Thanks so much man!

Answer (score 4):

Using the pipeline can result in a new line being added by powershell. You can use `Set-Clipboard` and it should avoid the newline issue.

You can also use the .NET option as well:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText("line1`r`nline2")
```

Comment: The querent didn't specify what version of PowerShell he's using, and `Set-Clipboard` isn't available in all versions. I've used the .NET technique in everything from PS2 to PS5, and I've even wrapped them into script cmdlets/advanced functions.

Comment: I am using v.5, sorry I had to look it up. I've only started using it yesterday so I am not too familiar with the differences in versions, or how important it is to mention the one I am using.

Comment: Set-Clipboard will work for you then. The .NET method will work in version 2 and up.