# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json Encoding Special Characters Issue

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, invoke-webrequest

I have this code in my powershell script and it doesn't do well on the special characters parts.

```
 $request = 'http://151.80.109.18:8082/vrageremote/v1/session/players'
 $a = Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" $request |
 ConvertFrom-Json    |
 Select -expand Data |
 Select -expand players |
 Select displayName, factionTag | Out-file "$scriptPath\getFactionTag.txt"
```

In my output file I only get '????' for any special characters. Does anyone know how I can get it to show special characters in my output file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Peter Schneider's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033574/45375) and [Nas' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033691/45375) both address *one* problem with your approach: You need to:

- either: access the `.Content` property on the response object returned by `Invoke-WebRequest` to get the actual *data* returned (as a JSON string), which you can then pass to `ConvertFrom-Json`.
- or: use `Invoke-RestMethod` instead, which returns the data *directly* and *parses it into custom objects*, so you can work with these objects directly, without the need for `ConvertTo-Json`; however, with a character-encoding problem such as in this case this is *not* an option, because explicit re-encoding of the JSON string is needed - see below.

However, **you still have a *character-encoding* problem**, because, in the **absence of `charset` information in the *response* header**, PowerShell interprets the UTF-8-encoded JSON string returned as [**ISO-8859-1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)-encoded, in Windows PowerShell as well as in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) **up to v7.3.3**, *except* that **v7.0+ defaults to UTF-8 for *JSON***, specifically.
**v7.4+** will use **UTF-8 as the *general* default**, i.e. for *all* media types.

There are two possible solutions:

- Preferably, amend the web service to include `charset=utf-8` in the response header's `ContenType` field.
- If you can't do that, you must **perform your own decoding**, based on the *raw bytes* of the response body, accessible via the `.RawContentStream` property:

Here's the implementation of the latter:

```
# Note that there's no point in using 
# -ContentType  "application/json; charset=utf-8" in this case,
# as -ContentType only applies to data sent *to* the web service.
$request = 'http://151.80.109.18:8082/vrageremote/v1/session/players'
$a = Invoke-WebRequest $request

# $a.Content cannot be used, because it contains the *misinterpreted* JSON string,
# but $a.RawContentStream provides access to the raw bytes,
# which you can decode into a string with the encoding of choice.
$jsonCorrected = 
  [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(
    $a.RawContentStream.ToArray()
  )

# Now process the reinterpreted string.
$jsonCorrected |
  ConvertFrom-Json    |
  Select -expand Data |
  Select -expand players |
  Select displayName, factionTag | Out-file "$scriptPath\getFactionTag.txt"
```

Note:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47961370/45375) provides **convenience function `ConvertTo-BodyWithEncoding`**, which wraps the functionality above.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Invoke-RestMethod` if you only need the json data without the `ParsedHtml`, `Headers` and other objects returned by `Invoke-WebRequest`

```
$request = 'http://151.80.109.18:8082/vrageremote/v1/session/players'
$a = Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" $request |
Select -expand Data |
Select -expand players |
Select displayName, factionTag | Out-file "$scriptPath\getFactionTag.txt"
```

Comment: Same result as the one above, This gets rid of the '????' characters but now I'm left with lots of 'Ð'. Like 'УРА' becomes 'Ð£Ð Ð'

Comment: That's helpful advice in general, but the problem here is one of character encoding, so there is a need to perform explicit re-encoding of the _string_ data received before further processing, so in this special case working with the `.Content` property of the `Invoke-WebRequest` response is required.

Comment: I was trying -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" in header object for my `Invoke-RestMethod` call and it didn't work , passing it like a separate parameter to `Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert the value of the `.Content` property to JSON:

```
$request = 'http://151.80.109.18:8082/vrageremote/v1/session/players'
$a = Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" $request

($a.Content | convertfrom-json).Data.Players | select DisplayName,FactionTag | Out-file "$scriptPath\getFactionTag.txt" -Encoding Default
```

Comment: This gets rid of the '????' characters but now I'm left with lots of 'Ð'. Like 'УРА' becomes 'Ð£Ð Ð'