# Invoke-RestMethod PowerShell problem with Encoding

Tags: powershell, encoding, character-encoding, invoke-restmethod

I am trying to use the Invoke-Restmethod to call a set of API's, but i have a problem with output encoding. What it could be

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'    
$Header = @{"Authorization" = "Token token_value"}
    
    $uri = "https://some_api_url"
    $team = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $Header -ContentType "text/*; charset=utf8"
    $team.last_name
```

Results:

[image]

PS Version:

[image]

Encoding Config in PS
[image]

website config:

[image]

Comment: Save your PowerShell script in UTF8

Comment: What matter is whether the _response_ from the web service indicates in its header that it is returning UTF-8. Does it? If not, and you have no way to change that, you'll have to manually _re-encode_ the response string and decode it again, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034595/45375). If that solves your problem, we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I know the problem is with Invoke command.
It get data in windows-1252 encoding and saves it in utf-8 format but without decoding.

Comment: If there's no `charset` header in the response, PowerShell assumes ISO-8859-1 encoding and that's what it uses to _decode_ the response into a .NET string (internally composed of UTF-16 code units). If the _actual_ encoding of the response is UTF-8, the decoding malfunctions. The previously linked answer shows you how to fix that problem _afterwards_. Have you tried it, and if it didn't work, how did it fail?

Comment: Saving to json and then editing data resolve problem with encoding

`$f = 'D:\temp\out.json'

Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $Header -OutFile $f
$json = Get-Content -Path $f -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: This confirms that your question is a duplicate, so I've marked  it as such. Your solution is conceptually simpler, but less efficient (the efficiency can be improved by omitting `Out-String` and using `-Raw` with `Get-Content`), though in practice that may not matter. I encourage you to post your solution as an answer to the linked duplicate.