# Cannot convert value to powershell

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, invoke-restmethod

I want to convert cmdlets to windows-1251 encoding so that Russian characters are displayed on the output.

My code:

```
$result = 'Invoke-RestMethod -Method "Post" -Uri https://ntfy.sh/most -Body "Hello 123 Привет" -UseBasicParsing'

$rus_result =  [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('windows-1251').GetString([Byte[]]$result)
```

PowerShell Errors:

> InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "Invoke-RestMethod -Method >"Post" -Uri https://ntfy.sh/most -Body "Hello 123 Привет" ->UseBasicParsing" to type "System.Byte[]". Error: "Cannot convert value >"Invoke-RestMethod -Method "Post" -Uri https://ntfy.sh/most -Body >"Hello 123 Привет" -UseBasicParsing" to type "System.Byte". Error: >"Input string was not in a correct format.""
> [image]

Comment: `'Invoke-RestMethod ...'` is a verbatim _string literal_, so whatever is inside `'...'` is assigned _as-is_ to `$result`. If you want to _execute a command_, remove the `'` chars.

Comment: @mklement0
I want to execute the command after converting Russian characters, otherwise they are replaced with question marks.

Comment: Character encoding is an unrelated problem.

Comment: I just don't understand how to do it right.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about what you're trying to do, and what the expected results are: what character encoding does the target web service expect? What is the character encoding it uses for its responses?

Comment: Everything happens in UTF-8

Comment: Try `-Content 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'` for _sending_. On _receiving_, [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) never reports _raw bytes_, from what I can tell. If you need to _reinterpret_ a misdecoded string, use the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034595/45375).

Comment: Also note that .NET strings use UTF-16LE, i.e. they're capable of representing _all_ Unicode characters. However, some Unicode characters may not _render_ correctly, in regular Windows console windows (provided by `conhost.exe`). You won't have that problem if you use [Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/windowsterminal) instead.