# Cannot convert value "version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument"

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a sample XML file `test.xml` that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Update>
    <foo>1.1.1</foo>
    <bar>12345</bar>
  </Update>
</Response>
```

I'm trying to use PowerShell to get the value of `foo`. I can download and save the file into `text.xml` and then access `foo`. This works:

```
Invoke-RestMethod $myurl | Out-File test.xml
[xml]$abc = (Get-Content test.xml) 
$abc.Response.Update.foo
```

However, I receive errors when I attempt to save the XML content into the `$abc` variable like this:

```
[xml]$abc = (Invoke-RestMethod $myurl)
```

Error:

```
MetadataError: Cannot convert value "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Update>
[...snip...]
  </Update>
</Response>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
```

What am I doing wrong here?

### Update #1

This produces no output and no errors:

```
$abc = Invoke-RestMethod $myurl
$abc.Response
$abc.Response.Update           
$abc.Response.Update.foo
```

Changing to `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
[xml]$abc = Invoke-WebRequest $myurl
```

Error is the same, but now there is three question marks in the beginning. So it's possible that the problem is somehow related to the file's encoding.

```
MetadataError: Cannot convert value "???<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Update>
[...snip...]
  </Update>
</Response>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
```

Comment: Maybe `$abc = [xml] $(Invoke-RestMethod $myurl)`?

Comment: What properties does invoke-restmethod return?  You probably only want something like the .content property.

Comment: @JosefZ This command fails with the same error.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` normally already returns an `[xml]` instance for you. Thus, if you omit the `[xml]` cast / type constraint, do you get the same error? If so, use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead, and examine the `.Content` property, which should contain the response _as plain text_. This might provide a clue as to why parsing as XML fails.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you. `$abc = Invoke-RestMethod $myurl` and `$abc.Response.Update.foo` don't produce any output (and no errors). I've just updated the question with other new details.

Comment: What does $abc produce?  Maybe invoke-webrequest gets a bom in the beginning.

Comment: @js2010 `[xml]$abc.Content                                             
InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Update> ...
`

Comment: `[xml]$abc
InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "???<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Update> ...`

Comment: try with `($xml = [xml]::new()).Load((Invoke-RestMethod $myurl))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symptom suggests that there are *three unrecognized characters* preceding the XML text returned by your web service.

- While three characters could generally indicate what constitutes a *mis-decoded* UTF-8 (pseudo) BOM,

  - (a) such a BOM is usually only present in *files on disk*, not in web-service responses
  - (b) even if it were mis-decoded as the default encoding used by the web cmdlets up to PowerShell 7.2.x, ISO-8859-1, it would print as `ï»¿`, not as `???`

Pragmatically speaking, assuming that the remaining text *is* properly decoded, you can simply skip the three characters as follows:

```bash
[xml] (Invoke-WebRequest $myUrl).Content.Substring(3)
```

If that doesn't help, use a text editor to examine the downloaded file and determine its de-facto encoding, then try to decode the *raw bytes* as a string with that encoding, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034595/45375).

Answer (score -1):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Update>
    <foo>1.1.1</foo>
    <bar>12345</bar>
  </Update>
</Response>
"@
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xml)
$update = $doc.Descendants("Update").Foreach([System.Xml.Linq.XElement])
$foo = $update.Element("foo").Value
$bar = $update.Element("bar").Value
Write-Host "foo = " $foo "bar = " $bar
```

Comment: You're showing a different solution to something that not only the OP already knows how to do, but knows how to do more simply (`[xml]$abc = (Get-Content test.xml)`). This question isn't about XML-parsing techniques, but about possible encoding problems. Your answer doesn't address the problem at hand and introduces incidental information without an explanation. In short: your answer is likely to be an unhelpful distraction to future readers.

Comment: @mklement0 : There is nothing wrong with the file and there is no encoding issues.