# Trouble Extracting Multilingual Data to JSON using Invoke-RestMethod in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, encoding

I am working on a PowerShell script that interacts with the DeepL API to retrieve data in multiple languages, including languages that use special characters such as French, Korean, Japanese... But I always get results like this:

```
{
    "Hello":  "ìë\u0085íì¸ì",
    "World":  "ì¸ê³"
}
```

Here's my current code:

```
function translate($text) {
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "DeepL-Auth-Key ...."
        "Accept-Charset" = "utf-8"
    }
    $body = @{
        "text" = "$text"
        "target_lang" = "KO"
    }
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate" `
        -Method Post `
        -Headers $headers `
        -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `
        -Body $body `

    return $response.translations.text
}

$wordList = @("Hello", "World")

$translations = @{}

foreach ($word in $wordList) {
    $translation = translate $word
    $translations[$word] = $translation
}

$translations | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "ko.json" -Encoding utf8
```

I've tried many parameters in headers, body, Out-File and attempted to replace Invoke-RestMethod without success."

---

Thanks for the comment, here is the correction

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest `
        -Uri "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate" `
        -Method Post `
        -Headers $headers `
        -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" `
        -Body $body `

    $encodedResponse = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($response.RawContentStream.ToArray())
    $jsonResponse = $encodedResponse | ConvertFrom-Json
    $translation = $jsonResponse.translations.text
    return $translation
```

Comment: If the response header doesn't explicitly specify UTF-8, Windows PowerShell will interpret the response as ISO-8859-1-encoded. If that is the problem, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034595/45375) for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for updating (note that you should post a comment @-mentioning a user you're responding to so as  to ensure that they'll get notified). Does this mean that your updated code _solves the problem_? If so, we can close your question as a duplicate of the [previously linked-to post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034595/45375).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 for your comments! The code you suggested resolved my issue, and I've successfully tested it. I agree with closing my question as a duplicate of the provided link. However, I'm not sure how to do this. Can you please guide me on the steps?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. You can click on the `Close` link below your question post, select the `Duplicate` option, paste the URL to the linked post into the search box, and click the `Vote to close` button. Let me know if you have trouble, and I'm happy to close the question for you.

Comment: Thank you, @mklement0, for the guidance. I've checked, and unfortunately, I only see the options "Share," "Edit," "Delete," and "Flag" below my question, but not the "Close" option. Could this be related to my Stack Overflow score or reputation? If that's the case, I would appreciate your help in closing the question for me.

Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, good point: It looks like 3000+ points are required - I had mistakenly assumed that you can always close your _own_ questions, but apparently not. Thanks for letting me know, I've now performed the duplicate closure myself.

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 for your quick help and for closing the question. I really appreciate your help and advice. Have a great day!

Comment: My pleasure, @tenshi. Thank you for your diligent follow-up regarding the duplicate closure.